# Manage Windows Server 2012 and trunk the Hyper-V VM (same physical NIC)

Tags: virtualization, switch, vlan, hyper-v-server-2012, trunk

I'm trying to use Hyper-V to deploy a pfSENSE box inside of it.
But, the scenario is:

3 VLANs

- VID: 1000
- VID: 2000
- VID: 3000

On a physical switch port, I've tagged the Server physical port with those 3 VID, and let untagged on VID 1

What I want to achieve in Windows Server 2012 R2, is to be able to manage the Physical Server thru the VID 2000 and be able to trunk the pfSENSE (VM) virtual NIC so pfSENSE can participate all 3 vlans broadcast domain.

Is that possible to do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

For your **host OS**, you can set its vlan ID from its virtual switch settings under VLAN ID. Your virtual switch needs to have the "Allow management OS to share this adapter" setting enabled.

[image]

```
Hyper-V Manager -> Virtual Switch Manager -> Your virtual switch -> VLAN ID
```

For your **VMs**, you can set a vlan ID for each network adapter individually. Your pfSense VM will need 3 adapters, all connected to the same virtual switch with a different VLAN ID.

[image]

```
Hyper-V Manager -> VM Settings -> Network Adapter
```